# On the bxslider, how to make fade li when click the only pagers?

Tags: jquery, bxslider

On the bxslider, how to make fade li when click the only pagers? I want to make the prev/next buttons are slide, and pagers fade.

This is what I have tried. Please help

```
<ul class="bxslider">
    <li>list 1</li> 
    <li>list 2</li>  
</ul> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({  
      captions: true
    }); 

    $('.bx-pager-link').click(function(){  
        slider.fade(); 
    }); 

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below code -
$('.bx-pager-link').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: true
});

Comment: slider fade possible but pager is not.have to write some custom js